# AngularJS set up binding without an isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is this the way to achieve read-only **binding** to an object attached in a parent directive's scope?

I really need the child directive to receive change notifications if the parent changes it's "$scope.thing".

Basically, I'm polling right now.  I'd like a callback method.

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.directive('myParent', function($compile) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope, $log) {
      $scope.thing = { awesome: 'sucky' };
      var count = 0;
      setInterval(function() { $scope.thing = { awesome: 'cool'+count++ }}, 2000); 
    },
    template: '<div><div my-child entity="thing"></div></div>'
  };
})
.directive('myChild', function($parse, $log) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var expression = attrs['entity'];
      scope.onetime = $parse(expression)(scope);
      $log.log('onetime');
      $log.log(scope.onetime);

      setInterval(function () {
          if (expression) {
              scope.intervaled = $parse(expression)(scope);
              scope.$apply();
              $log.log('interval');
              $log.log(scope.intervaled);
          }
      }, 2000);
    }, 
    template: '<span>{{onetime}}</span>-<span>{{intervaled}}</span>'
  };
})
```

And the obligatory plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2jfa1dcwguO400zRjJxU?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pooling just take advantage of the AngularJS $digest loop and observe the changes in the attribute:

```
  var entityValue = $parse(attrs.entity);

  scope.$watch(entityValue, function(newValue, oldValue){
     scope.intervaled = newValue;
  });
```

The `$scope.$apply` should be always called on the end where you know that you are outside of the AngularJS world - in this case on the sending end:

```
    setInterval(function() { 
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.thing = { awesome: 'cool'+count++ }  
      })
    }, 2000)
```

And finally the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/LBwl5IeA3rXrHfTLEFMZ?p=preview

Please note that having a directive with a template that doesn't isolate a scope is playing with fire as your directive might easily override data needed by other parts of your application (`intervaled` in your case).

Comment: Thanks, and special thanks for the tip about isolate scope.  So in general I should use isolate scope if my directive has a template?

Comment: Yes, I would say that a good rule of thumb is this: if you've got a template that reads _directive specific_ model (which means that you've got directive specific variables on a scope), you should isolate a scope in order to avoid potential clashes.